# I am getting a 'NoClassDefFoundError'

Tags: java, lwjgl, noclassdeffounderror

I am just starting to learn LWJGL3, but fot some reason, the imports don't work. I tried 2 methods of installing LWJGL3, first time I followed a video tutorial, second time I installed it how the official installation guide told me to ([Guide](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/1.2.-Install)). All of the JARs that come with LWJGL3 are included in the JRE System Library. The error appears as soon as I try to utilise glfw.

[Image of my workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRQxU.png)

Code:

```
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWVidMode;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (!glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to initialise GLFW");
        }
        
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        long window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "LWJGL Porgramme", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), 0);
        if(window == 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to create window");
        }
        
        GLFWVidMode videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window, (videoMode.width() - 640) / 2, (videoMode.height() - 480)/ 2);
        
        glfwShowWindow(window);
        
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            glfwPollEvents();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFW
        at Main.main(Main.java:6)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 1 more
```

Edit: ClassLoader can't load the class, but I don't know why it can't load the class, since it is added in "external JARs". [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHjBn.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "are included in the JRE System Library".  If you are out of simpler options, you should be able to 1) print out the classpath in the module that is attempting the import (using that module/class's ClassLoader), 2) confirm that the jar you think the class in question is in is indeed on the class path, 3) unzip the jar and make sure that the class is actually in there, with the right fully qualified name.  Do you have any other libraries you've installed that you could try to access to determine if the problem is this particular library, or non-built-in libraries in general

Comment: I assume that your code compiles. That would mean that the "build" configuration in your IDE is correct. So compare that with your run configuration. Are you using Intellij as your IDE?

Comment: I am using Eclipse as my IDE.

Comment: Steve, by "are included in the JRE System Library", I meant that I added them in "external JARs", in build path. And I don't see any other libraries that I have installed.

Comment: What version of Eclipse and what version of java?

Comment: The latest version of Eclipse, 2020-09 and for Java, it's verison 8, update 261. But I don't think that it matters, because I can programme with Java without any problems, but it's LWJGL3 that doesn't work.

Comment: It matters because JDK versions after 8 use modules, so I wanted to know if you are using modules or not. And each Eclipse version supports different versions of java so I wanted to know if your Eclipse version supports your JDK version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took way too long, but I got it to work. I installed LWJGL3 with Gradle, made a Gradle project and copied the Java source code to the Gradle project.